# Django get client user name when access webAPI hosted in IIS from client browser

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, iis-8, restful-authentication

We have a django restful api to save data in SQL Database. This API is hosted in IIS and consumed by Angular application. 
How to get client user name who browsed it from local machine?

There is no user model available in database.

Comment: what do you mean by "client user name"?

Comment: Here client user name means: My username (ParasJain) 
if I access the angular application and consumed Python: 'Created By' field uses Server name is stamped as an audit instead of the user name

Comment: but where does that username come from if it's not in the database? Where do you set your username? Maybe show us the code (django) where you process the request from the client and want to add the username.

Comment: Users logged-in with windows credentials

Comment: afaik web browsers don't have access to that information. So that's not possible.

Comment: but there might be an exception for IE/Edge: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441209/grab-username-from-ie-to-authenticate-against-ldap/1441494#1441494

Comment: But this can be doable when we have an API in c#