# Detect windows domain username in PHP

Tags: php

Is there anyway, in PHP, to detect someone's username?

I want to track the users that visit and download particular files on our internal site?

Comment: Whats wrong with just using say browser cookies?

Comment: Please tell us more about the setup of your "internal site" and the infrastructure. E.g. which webserver do you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean Active Directory authentication, and you're running Internet Explorer on the client end, this seems to be possible in some circumstances. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168610/can-you-get-a-windows-ad-username-in-php).

Comment: Firefox supports integrated authentication, too. see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Integrated_Authentication

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't read a visitor's Windows username.