# Find Windows username in PHP

Tags: php, windows

How can I retrieve the username of the currently logged on Windows user in PHP?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you get a Windows (AD) username in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/168610/can-you-get-a-windows-ad-username-in-php)

Comment: By executing the PHP locally? look at getenv(). Remotely? you can't

Comment: Francesco, I have already try but without success, do you have some example ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will display username under which PHP/WebServer is run. If you run such script in CLI mode, it will show your login name, otherwise it will be username for the webserver user:

```
$obj = new COM("wscript.network");
echo $obj->username;
```

Further information

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.com-get.php
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3fxhka75%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

---

An Alternative would be via WMIC:

```
exec('wmic COMPUTERSYSTEM Get UserName', $user)
print_r($user);
```

For more details on `WMIC`, see

- [WMIC - Take Command-line Control over WMI](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742610.aspx) and
- [Windows Management Instrumentation Command](http://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html)

Comment: Nice,but he gave me just "SYSTEM" as word
Do you know why?

Comment: This code will display username under which PHP/WebServer is run. If you run such script in CLI mode, it will show you your login, otherwise it will be username which Apapche/IIS app pool is run under.

Comment: Yes infact I replace username with Computername and He give me the Server Name, means the script is performed at server level, I thinks should be necessary run it at client server

Comment: I try this code but doesn't work  :(

<script  language="javascript">
     var WshNetwork = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Network");
     var Text = "User name : " + WshNetwork.Username;
     alert (Text);
</script> 

Do you see something strange ?

Comment: @LazyOne
I try this code but doesn't work :( '<script language="javascript"> var WshNetwork = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Network"); var Text = "User name : " + WshNetwork.Username; alert (Text); </script>'  Do you see something strange ?

Comment: @PJK72 That's Javascript not PHP.

Comment: @LazyOne Yes I know, but as sayd you before with PHP he give me the "SYSTEM" word and not <<my username>>

Comment: @PJK72 What I meant to say there -- is that I'm not that good with JavaScript (just some pretty basic jQuery usage) and cannot really advice here. In any case -- that code may only work in IE if at all.

Comment: @LazyOne 
Very Clear, I know that with JQuery Library I shoud find the solution, but I don't want use it, for not  create too much lines in the code only for recovery the username
thanks a lot.

Comment: @LazyOne
OK, now it's clear, using a Script code, need to change the IE security to LOW, that's all

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are referring to the username of the user running PHP, this can be retrieved using:

```
$username = getenv("username");
```

If you mean the username of the person viewing the webpage - due to security issues in browsers, this is not possible.

Comment: I sure hope that's not possible.

Comment: Most definitely not possible. Well, you can in IE using ActiveX (if security settings are right, and permissions are given), but otherwise its not happening.

Comment: You can get many other informations, though, they are stored in `$_SERVER`.

Comment: Yes, I can Understand, but why with Windows Tools (ASP, SQLServer Sharpoint Ect. Ect ) it's possible? it's strange, no ?

Comment: Even with Windows things, you won't be able to retrieve the username of the person accessing the website itself. This is not something the browser will ever allow you to access. It doesn't matter what's going on behind the scenes.

Comment: On IIS 7 this is the same as `$_SERVER["USERNAME"]` and it shows me  not the username, but computername with $ at the end (like `MYPC$`). If such code run in CLI mode (within IDE, for example), it shows user name indeed.