# Can I use superglobals to authenticate users of a PHP page?

Tags: php, apache, http-authentication

I have a problem that I'm hoping you can help with.

I'm wondering if there is a way to use superglobals to authenticate users for PHP pages?

Here's my situation:

- All users will be accessing my page(S) from our work network and have been authenticated using their Windows passwords.
- I don't have access to those passwords, so I can't ask them to authenticate using them.
- I'd rather not ask the users to remember another pw.

I want the page to be able to do things like:
- Say "Hi Tev, welcome to your portal".
- Automatically pull the username so the page can automatically display their stats/calls/tickets

I thought that REMOTE_USER would be able to do this, but my apache server (which I'm an admin for) doesn't seem to return this. Do I need to change something in my Apache configuration?

I've looked through a lot of PHP and Apache forums, but haven't been able to find an answer.

---

On behalf of requester:

Thanks for the responses, but we might not be able to connect to the LDAP Active directory Server.

In php.ini, we set  `register_globals = On`

When running  `print_r($GLOBALS)` on our server,  under  `[_SERVER] => Array`, `[REMOTE_USER]` is missing.

`[REMOTE_ADDR]` is present alright, but not `[REMOTE_USER]`.

Is there any way to add it?

Comment: I've never done this before, but you may be looking for something like http://adldap.sourceforge.net/, you probably want something like Active Directory Authentication and be able to get the LDAP information.

Comment: Like Matt mentions below. We won't be able to connect to LDAP (I'm an admin on the linux server, but don't have any access to the Windows server), which is why we weer exploring the REMOTE_USER superglobal.

Answer (score 1):

If your users are authenticated on your work network, then what you need is to connect to the LDAP / Active Directory server. This question should help you:

[Can you get a Windows (AD) username in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168610/can-you-get-a-windows-ad-username-in-php)