# PHP transparent login with Windows (AD) credentials

Tags: php, apache, windows, authentication

Is this possible to start php session using current windows (*Active Directory*) credentials?
Its important that authorization should be transparent, no user action required.
Windows user name and password should be compared with users table in *mysql* db.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you get a Windows (AD) username in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/168610/can-you-get-a-windows-ad-username-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

There is an Apache module for NTLM on http://github.com/rsim/mod_ntlm. You can find details about its installation and configuration on http://blog.rayapps.com/2008/12/02/ntlm-windows-domain-authentication-for-rails-application/.

After you installed the module and configured as described mod_ntlm will set the REMOTE_USER environment variable with authenticated Windows username.