# How to automatically authenticate LDAP in Windows using PHP

Tags: php, iis, ldap

In PHP (running on a Windows server under IIS), I have a login page that authenticates the entered username/password against the Windows domain controller.

The code uses `ldap_connect` and `ldap_bind` against user input (username+password).

But I want the PHP code to automatically pull the logged in user, so they don't have to enter a username and password. The user would already be logged on the computer under a domain, using Internet Explorer.

How can I have PHP code automatically authenticate (in IE) against the logger in user on the Windows machine?

`$_SERVER["AUTH_USER"]` and `$_SERVER["REMOTE_USER"]` do not work, it only returns a blank string in IE.

I found I could use this Javascript:

```
ActiveXObject("WScript.Network")
```

(and then pulling the username) But that doesn't work for me, as it requires the user to have their ActiveX trust levels set correctly first (which loosens security for the user).

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/168610/can-you-get-a-windows-ad-username-in-php), as it might have some additional insight.

Comment: @MrSlayer Hmm I'm trying `$_SERVER["AUTH_USER"]` but under IE it's just returning a blank string.

Comment: Are you maintaining your own server?  Have you looked into mod_auth_sspi, as suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1958096/1028949)?

Comment: @MrSlayer I saw that yeah, but isn't that for Apache only? I'm running IIS.

Comment: My mistake, I misread the question.  Is anonymous access enabled?

Comment: @MrSlayer I don't believe so, I definitely don't want anonymous (non-domain users) access to this site.

Comment: Did you try $_SERVER["REMOTE_USER"]?

Comment: @MartinWilson Yes, same thing. It returned a blank.