# Getting blank value for $_SERVER['AUTH_USER']

Tags: php, active-directory, windows-server-2008

I have a PHP app running on Windows 2008 server R2, which authenticates users against Active Directory using PHP's LDAP library.

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168610/can-you-get-a-windows-ad-username-in-php), I'm looking to use `$_SERVER['AUTH_USER']`, but I'm getting a blank value for it. Same for `AUTH_TYPE` and `AUTH_PASSWORD`. The variables are declared, but none of them have any value assigned to them.

I've enabled both the Basic Authentication and Windows Authentication roles (through Server Manager), but neither has solved the issue.

I'm using PHP 5.3.14, Zend Server CE and IIS 7.5.

I need to apply a single sign on solution, but without being able to fetch the currently logged in user's credentials, I'm at a loss.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Since when is `AUTH_USER` a valid index of `$_SERVER`? Unless this has something to do with LDAP?

Comment: Did you check `$_SERVER['REMOTE_USER']`?

Comment: @Matt I think it's being added by IIS. This is the first time I've seen that index.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski REMOTE_USER is declared, but it's also empty

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I got it working by disabling Anonymous Authentication in IIS, and enabling Windows Authentication (I thought Windows Authentication was already enabled, but it turns out the role was simply installed.) Now `$_SERVER['AUTH_USER']` and `$_SERVER['REMOTE_USER']` are populated.

Comment: Is that all you did? I tried that, but it still isn't getting set.

Comment: strike that - the key thing was to disable Anonymous Authentication

Answer (score 2):

I believe the correct index for the authenticated user is `$_SERVER['REMOTE_USER']`.

Comment: REMOTE_USER is declared, but it's empty

Answer (score 1):

According to the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php), the correct index seems to be `PHP_AUTH_USER`.

Try using `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']`.

Comment: $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] isn't declared.