# Windows Automatic Authentication with PHP

Tags: php, authentication, active-directory, ntlm

First of all, sorry per my poor english, it’s not a primary language. 
So, the context is: I'm working on a intranet site developed in **php** hosted at a **windows 2012 server with IIS**. This site should have the authentication system integrated with the Active Directory.  I managed to integrate it using the ldap_bind function, which is perfect for when the user is out of the network. But, I also need it to **automatically login** when the user is already **logged at the windows**, how to get to this result? What to search for?

Thank you very much.

Comment: have a look at this, it might help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/168610/can-you-get-a-windows-ad-username-in-php

Comment: Thanks for that! It really helps with the username, but what about the password? Sorry, couldn't understand how to proceed with authentication with only the username. I'm really not used to work in a IIS / Windows environment so if you could elaborate a little would be really nice (:

Comment: I believe there isn't a way to send the password, but that AUTH_USER is *only* set if the user is authenticated. I don't have experience with windows/IIS, I just did a quick google.

Comment: LoL that really makes sense, feeling stupid hehe, thank you very much o/