# use ms access vba udf in php

Tags: php, ms-access, user-defined-functions

i have ms access database as backend and it connect to php as frontend by odbc_connection. is it possible to use vba udf that i create in ms access database by vba in php file?

> vba code in ms access module:

```
public function GetUserName()
     GetUserName = Environ("username")
End function
```

> code in php file

```
$con = odbc_connect("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver(*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq=\\sha\\test\\Main_be.accdb","","");
$sql = "select ID , GetUserName() as username from ft";
$rs = odbc_exec($con , $sql);
```

when i open php file the below error display

```
Warning: odbc_exec(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Undefined function 'GetUserName' in expression, SQL state 37000 in SQLExecDirect in C:\xampp\httdocs\test\BE.php on line 67
```

Comment: I wouldn't get my hopes up, be glad that it works at all. This isn't a given. The only reason it actually does "something", is because you're using Windows.

Comment: It looks like a missing driver issue. Does reducing to `$sql = "select ID from ft";` return values?

Comment: yes. it return.

Comment: Review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168610/can-you-get-a-windows-ad-username-in-php